# Cassandra 1.1 or 1.2 for production usage?

Tags: cassandra, corruption

We are encountering random SSTable corruptions with 1.2.3/1.2.4 (Datastax Community Edition) on single node development machines with a mixed read/write load using a data model with wide rows from a number of columns POV. Writes are more frequent than reads though. The problems manifests with stack traces like:

```
ERROR [ReadStage:13899] 2013-04-24 07:09:00,770 CassandraDaemon.java (line 132) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:13899,5,main]
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1582)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.computeNext(SimpleSliceReader.java:106)
... many more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(Unknown Source)
... many more
```

or

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnSerializer$CorruptColumnException: invalid column name length 0
```

Unfortunately, we don't have a reproducible test case yet, because this happens randomly (e.g. after a few days) and not immediately.

I have also researched similar issues with 1.2 in this/other forum(s).

The question is: What is your experience with Cassandra 1.2 in production or would you recommend 1.1 being 1.2.4 the most recent release to date in the 1.2 series?

While we encounter these issues on single node development environments, things might get backed up when running the whole stuff in a cluster served by several nodes, but in our opinion things should run on a single node without corruption as well.

Any hints are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you solved this problem? I got the same exception, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have better experience with cassandra-1.1 in production. Current version 1.2.6 still do not passes our heavy preproduction testing.